# Type Class w/ `min`?

Tags: class, haskell

Given the `Ord` Type Class:

```
Prelude> :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  (<) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (<=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
  (>=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  max :: a -> a -> a
  min :: a -> a -> a
```

Is there a type class that provides a `min : a` field/function for a given type?

Example:

`min :: Int` would output the minimum `Int` value.

Comment: What you're looking for is the [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) typeclass.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`Bounded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded), which contains [`minBound`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:minBound).

Comment: Thanks (will accept when able)! I see this Type Class has functions: `minBound` and `maxBound`. Is there a `step` function, i.e. how to increment one element from `minBound` to `maxBound`, available in another type class?

Comment: @KevinMeredith that's part of `Enum` and called `succ`(essor)

Comment: @KevinMeredith But beware that `iterate succ minBound` is not guaranteed to hit every possible value of a given type. See also the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package, which is specifically for iterating over all of a given type's possible values.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielWagner. Could you please point me to an explanation of why it's "not guaranteed to hit every possible value of a given type?"

Comment: @KevinMeredith `succ (1.4 :: Double)` gives `2.4`. Now `Double` isn't a member of `Bounded`, so there's no `minBound`. But if we accept the behaviour of `Enum Double` as a valid `Enum` instance (I'm a bit dubious about that, to be honest), then it's "allowed" for `succ` to "skip over" possible values, so there's no reason to expect that `iterate succ minBound` will hit everything for an arbitrary type in `Enum` and `Bounded`. That said, the only instances of `Bounded` in the Prelude are Word, Ordering, Int, Char, Bool, and (), (and tuples thereof), which should behave sensibly.

Comment: Thanks, @Ben. Does `Bounded` have any Type Class Laws? I didn't see any in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I don't know that there are any laws, but I would expect `minBound <= x` and `maxBound >= x` to hold whenever a type is both `Bounded` and `Ord`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith The description "The Bounded class is used to name the upper and lower limits of a type. Ord is not a superclass of Bounded since types that are not totally ordered may also have upper and lower bounds." from the docs you linked reads to me like an informal specification of the law from Daniel's comment, but it's not really explicit that that's intended as a prerequisite for writing a Bounded instance. Some of the early classes weren't really designed based on the idea of classes having laws; we'd probably design them differently today (`Enum` itself is one I certainly would).